# Start Mysql when Mysql cluster is installed

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I have a problem with starting mysql when i have installd mysql cluster on a singel server.

I have read somewhere that if you install Mysql cluster you do not have to download the MySQL server or client (apt-get install mysql-server / client)
becuse these will end up in conflict. Mysql packets should be in the mysql-cluster-gpl-7.4.7-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64 file that I downloaded from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/cluster/).

But how can I start mysql without install mysql-server or client?

If I write `mysql` in promp, I get this error message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

And if i search "mysql-cluster-gpl-7.4.7-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64" then i cant find any matching files to mysqld.sock

I have also tried to start mysqld but i got alot off errors.

```
2015-08-19 14:52:00 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/local/mysql-cluster-gpl-7.4.7-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql/data/Idrottskoll.lower-test
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql/data/Idrottskoll.lower-test
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)

2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_cache: 431 (requested 2000)

2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Unknown error 1017
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [ERROR] InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown option '--ndbcluster'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Binlog end
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-08-19 14:52:00 4208 [Note]
```

I'm obviously new to programming, and could really use your help to explain how mysql works with mysql cluster.

I have followed the following [link](http://www.catharinegeek.com/set-up-mysql-cluster-on-ubuntu-14041/) to install mysql cluster:

Mysql Cluster seems to work:

```
[ndbd(NDB)] 1 node(s)
id=2    @46.21.99.140  (mysql-5.6.25 ndb-7.4.7, Nodegroup: 0, *)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @46.21.99.140  (mysql-5.6.25 ndb-7.4.7)

[mysqld(API)]   1 node(s)
id=3    @46.21.99.140  (mysql-5.6.25 ndb-7.4.7)
```

If I type: `ps aux | grep mysql`

```
root      3800  0.0  0.0   4440   752 ?        S    14:24   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/myname.pid

mysql     3951  0.4  5.7 1514076 465052 ?      Sl   14:24   0:05 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/myname.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/myname.pid --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock


my.cnf

[mysqld]
# Options for mysqld process:
ndbcluster                      # run NDB storage engine

basedir = /usr/local/mysql
datadir = /usr/local/mysql/data
#socket= /tmp/mysql.sock


[mysql_cluster]
# Options for MySQL Cluster processes:
ndb-connectstring=xx.xx.xx.xxx  # location of management server
```

Comment: sock files are created by running processes, and generally are NOT packed up in a .tar.gz. either your client has been told to look for the mysql socket file in the wrong spot, or the mysql server isn't running, and therefore hasn't created the socket file.

Comment: But when i type ps aux | grep mysql  mysqld is there and running. and [mysqld(API)] is running if i check Mysql cluster. ??

Comment: note the `#socket` file - it's commented out, therefore the server is using the compiled-in location, which is somewhere different than where the client is trying to look.

Comment: Thanks for your response, The problem with the out quoted line #socket= /tmp/mysql.sock is that its not the same file that mysql is searching for. Mysql is searching for mysqld.sock

Comment: exactly. the mysql client expects to find the file where you error message says it is, but the server is putting it somewhere else. you need to uncomment that socket line and put in the SAME path.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works! I replaced #socket= /tmp/mysql.sock with socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock and removed the commented. Created a folder called mysqld and a new file in that folder called mysqld.sock.

After reboot mysql started!

Thanks Marc B for your help!